# IBM cloudant NoSql communication with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to databases. Ive created a Nosql db on the IBM bluemix platform and I would like to access it from unity.

I was wondering if the www class would be sufficient to query the database? Would I need to add authentication etc? I can find samples for firebase and Aws with unity easily but I'm flying in the dark a bit with regards to cloudant

has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloudant database doesn't require any "drivers" or any special libraries to work with Unity. As long as you can make HTTP requests from your application, then Cloudant will be able to act as a data store.

You might want to try the [Unity WebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) object which is a lower-level abstraction than the 'www' library you suggest.

The Cloudant API Reference is [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/index.html#api-reference-overview).